# calculating sum of rows with identical id

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's imagine a table with two columns ex:

```
| Value | ID |
+-------+----+
| 2     | 1  |
| 3     | 1  |
| 4     | 1  |
| 1     | 2  |
| 2     | 2  |
| 2     | 2  |
```

What I am trying to do is to calculate the sum of those with similar id and display them in different table like:

```
| Sum | ID |
+-----+----+
| 9   | 1  |
| 5   | 2  |
```

and so on.

I could find a sum of a known id by

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 1;
```

However not sure on how to find sum of different id's separately, could you give an idea on how to proceed?

Comment: please try to do it yourself first. A simple google search would have helped you with this.

Comment: @Debabrata you are right, my main query is a bit more complicated than this one, when I first used `group by` got some error thought that I am doing something wrong, should have searched more diligently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select SUM(VALUE),ID FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) Sum, ID FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT SUM(VALUE),ID FROM MYTABLE Group By ID
```